Autoscaling scheduled policy with desired capacity
For AWS autoscaling policy, we can set desired capacity.
If I set a scheduled policy for a certain peak period with desired capacity as 10, then what happens to number of instances when peak period is over? Would I still have 10 ec2 instances running or some are removed?

From my experience, when you configure a scheduled scaling policy for an AWS Auto Scaling group to increase the desired capacity to 10 instances during a peak period, the Auto Scaling group ensures that the number of running instances matches this desired capacity.
After the peak period ends, the desired capacity needs to be explicitly adjusted back to a lower value if fewer instances are required. If no action is taken, the number of EC2 instances will remain at 10. However, if dynamic scaling policies based on metrics like CPU utilization are active, they could automatically reduce the desired capacity when the demand drops, terminating excess instances. If there are no such policies, you would need to manually adjust the desired capacity down or set another scheduled action to decrease the capacity after the peak.
Changing the desired capacity results in AWS Auto Scaling starting or terminating instances to match the new desired capacity, selecting instances to terminate based on termination policies defined in the Auto Scaling group. It’s best practice to configure both scaling up and down policies, either scheduled or dynamic, to handle fluctuations in load efficiently. Without a specific action to reduce the desired capacity after the peak, the number of instances will remain at the increased level.
Hope this answers your question.
